# What does the scheme dropdown menu do in Phpstorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

In the `settings` window of Phpstorm, there is a dropdown box labelled `scheme`

[image]

What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it do?

You may be surprised .. but it allows you to choose another (different) Code Style scheme for this project.

PhpStorm supports **globally defined schemas** (by default it provides only one -- "Default") which can be used by any project and **project-specific schema** called "Project" which available for this project only (and stored together with other project-specific settings).

You can read more in [official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-style.html?search=code%20style#d604361e122).

---

The Code Style is used for code formatting: be it automatic as you type / use live templates etc .. or manual reformat via `Code | Reformat Code...`

Comment: ah, thanks LazyOne! I didnt realise Phpstorm had a dedicated sub-scheme  just for `code style` - which was a bit of a surprise :)

Comment: Well .. different projects (especially frameworks/CMS) have their own style guides for the code. It would be obvious that IDE would need some system in place to support switching between them .. otherwise it would be a nightmare for user to reconfigure this every time they switch to another project. Surely, you can use `Set From...` button/link (e.g. available on page for PHP) to quickly "import" specific style into your schema, but you may still have your own preferences (which that code style may simply not cover).

Answer (score 1):

It's used to

> choose the code style scheme to be used as the base for your custom coding style for the selected language ([Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-code-style.html)).

In other words: after selecting a scheme, you can set different **formatting options**, like tabs vs spaces, tab size or line breaks etc. To use those settings in your current project, you need to click `Manage`, select your edited scheme and click `Copy to Project`. After this, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (`Code > Reformat Code...`) in the editor to reformat a file according to those scheme settings.